# Getting directions with google maps from Angular returns ok 200, but displays CORS issue

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) to get directions using google maps.

I have an angular http get method in a service:

```
 getDirections(){
        return this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood4&key=' + '<myKey>');
      }
```

And in my component, I subscribe to this service:

```
this.googleMapsService.getDirections().subscribe(response => {
      console.log('directions retrieved', response);
    }, error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    })
```

In the console network requests, it seems to return ok, 200. However, in the console, it responds:

```
Origin http://localhost:4200 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
```

I am able to see a response by entering the URL directly into the browser. I have not restricted access to use the key; I have kept it open to all URLs. I also get an error logged in the console:

```
[object Object]: {error: Object, headers: Object, message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error", name: "HttpErrorResponse", ok: false...}
```

I think that I may need to use JSONP to get this to work. Is this the case? I have tried following this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946417/2945345) (I am on version 4,4), but when it tries to read the response, it hits an error reading the json:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Error: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback. at HTMLScriptElement.onLoad
```

This error may be related to this: [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8153). My updated http code is as follows:

```
  getDirections(){
        let params = new HttpParams()
        .append('origin', 'Disneyland')
        .append('destination', 'Universal+Studios+Hollywood4')
         .append('key', '<my key>')
        .append('format', 'json');
      let url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?${params.toString()}`;
      return this.http.jsonp(url, 'callback');
  }
```

Comment: This seem to be a CORS issue and no modern browsers, as far as I know, allow this for security reasons. What is the status you get?

Comment: The status in the console is 200.

Comment: it seems like a CORS issue. If you call the query via URL you get a response because you are correctly using the Web Service API (If I understand the above correctly). However if you want to call the API without getting a CORS related error, you must use the JS API with a callback function in your HTML/JS code, not from a localhost or simple HTTP server, if that's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CORS issue.  You can't directly access data from another host through the browser.  Best bet is to whip up a local server app that wraps the call to google, and then call the local server end point.  You should be able to achieve this relatively quickly using express.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: I think you are mistaken. You can access data from another host through the browser. I have done this many times. It is up to the host whether it wants to restrict CORS access. It seems that the error here is because it does not respond with an expected header.

Comment: Well yes you are right, but so many APIs do restrict CORS access.

Comment: True, I have checked the settings on this maps API and it is not restricting CORS access.