# Gettings No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present error to external API

Tags: angular, cors

I don't understand why but I keep getting a CORS error when I send a request to an external API no matter what I do. How do I fix this?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YtsService {
  url = 'https://yts.tl/api/v2/list_movies.jsonp';
  headers;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    this.headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
    };
  }

  getMovies(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url, { headers: this.headers });
  }
}
```

The API doesn't even require authentication.

This is the error I get in my console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://yts.tl/api/v2/list_movies.jsonp'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.
>
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://yts.tl/api/v2/list_movies.jsonp with MIME type text/html. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you're trying to call a `jsonp` endpoint, try use `HttpClientJsonpModule` module instead. Might not be a `cors` issue.

See this link for examples:

[Angular jsonp calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273738/angular-jsonp-calls)

Comment: I think this could be it. I will test it tonight thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CORS errors come from the backend, not the frontend. The API you are requesting does not allow requests from your origin — it is likely that it is not a public API. There is nothing you can do on the frontend to prevent CORS errors, as CORS is a security system implemented by the backend to prevent unwanted requests.

Comment: But I can just access the address? You can too https://yts.tl/api/v2/list_movies.jsonp