# In Angular 9 - How to fetch a JSONP that doesn't have a callback function?

Tags: angular, api, jsonp, angular9

I'm trying to fetch de data the URL below:

http://storage.googleapis.com/nacleanopenworldprodshards/Nations_cleanopenworldprodeu1.json

I'm using Angular 9, and this is my service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NationsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    const url = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/nacleanopenworldprodshards/Nations_cleanopenworldprodeu1.json';

    return this.http.jsonp(url, 'callback');
  }

}
```

Simple enough, right? but it doesn't work. Because the "API" doesn't have a callback function. I searched a lot in stackoverflow but I did not find how to solve this.

Does anybody knows of a way to get the data using Angular 9?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular jsonp calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273738/angular-jsonp-calls)

Comment: The URL from where you are fetching data doesnt return a valid JSON, make sure it returns a valid JSON object.

Comment: @R.Richards thanks for your answer, but I actually tested my code with other jsonp APIs and the code is working fine for them. It is only for this specific API from my original post that it doesn't work. And I'm not sure what should I do to make it work.

Comment: @KamranKhatti I don't have access to change the content of the URL unfortunately.

Comment: @PedroSaad if API returns error and we dont have access to fix that API error then how come we fix it from front end? If you dont have access to change then tell someone to fix it who has access of it no other solution.